# iOS MapKit max zoom level

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, mapkit

Is there a way to increase the maximum zoom level of MKMapKit? As I zoom in further - eventually it no longer allows me to continue to zoom. Can this be overridden to allow for higher zoom levels?

Answer (score 2):

***No**, you cannot.*

The Map is compiled by google and has its limitations on how close you can zoom in. ***IF*** they were to update their maps to an even higher resolution and depth, the iOS SDK will *hopefully* be adapted accordingly.

You could cheat around this by enabling the accessibility options which then give you the possibility to zoom in the entire iPhone using a **three-finger-tap**.